# Swift 3 and CGContextDrawImage

Tags: core-graphics, swift3

I want to translate this line to the Swift 3 current syntax code but seems there are some problems:

```
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRect(x:0.0,y: 0.0,width: image!.size.width,height: image!.size.height), image!.cgImage)
```

According to the [CoreGraphics.apinotes](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/apinotes/CoreGraphics.apinotes) `CGContextDrawImage` was converted to `CGContext.draw` :

```
Name: CGContextDrawImage
  # replaced by draw(_ image: CGImage, in rect: CGRect, byTiling: Bool = false)
  SwiftName: CGContext.__draw(self:in:image:)
  SwiftPrivate: true
```

When I try to do :

```
 CGContext.draw(context as! CGImage, in: CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width: image!.size.width, height: image!.size.height), byTiling: false)
```

Seems there is some simple syntax that disturb the compiler but I cannot see (in fact I receive a typical ambiguous error):

[image]

Can anyone help me with this new swift 3 syntax code?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to call it as if it's an instance method of `CGContext`:

```
context.draw(image!.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0.0,width: image!.size.width,height: image!.size.height))
```

Check [the latest reference of `CGContext`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext).

Comment: Thank you , it works perfectly. 'self' initial property of the example have distracted me from the objective :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found an another very good solution for this issue which i am using currently. You just need to pass the image as an arugument to this method after capturing image using UIImagePickerController. It works well for all version of iOS and also for both portrait and landscape orientations of Camera. It checks for EXIF property of image using UIImageOrientaiton and accordind to the value of orientation, it transforms & scales the image so you will get the same return image with same orientation as your camera view orientation.

Here i have kept maximum resolutions of 3000 so that the image quality doesn't get spoiled specially while you are using retina devices but you can change its resolution as per your requirement.

```
func scaleAndRotateImage(image: UIImage, MaxResolution iIntMaxResolution: Int) -> UIImage {
        let kMaxResolution = iIntMaxResolution
        let imgRef = image.cgImage!
        let width: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.width)
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.height)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        var bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        if Int(width) > kMaxResolution || Int(height) > kMaxResolution {
            let ratio: CGFloat = width / height
            if ratio > 1 {
                bounds.size.width = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio
            }
            else {
                bounds.size.height = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio
            }
        }
        let scaleRatio: CGFloat = bounds.size.width / width
        let imageSize = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(imgRef.width), height: CGFloat(imgRef.height))

        var boundHeight: CGFloat
        let orient = image.imageOrientation
        // The output below is limited by 1 KB.
        // Please Sign Up (Free!) to remove this limitation.

        switch orient {
        case .up:
            //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        case .upMirrored:
            //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)

        case .down:
            //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))

        case .downMirrored:
            //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0.0, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        case .leftMirrored:
            //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.height, y: imageSize.width)

            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2) / 2.0)
            break

        default: print("Error in processing image")
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        if orient == .right || orient == .left {
            context?.scaleBy(x: -scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: -height, y: 0)
        }
        else {
            context?.scaleBy(x: scaleRatio, y: -scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: -height)
        }
        context?.concatenate(transform)
        context?.draw(imgRef, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        let imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageCopy!
    }
```